# CompoundIndex that allows different combinations

Tags: mongodb, nosql, key, unique

I'm trying to achieve an unique index on a mongodb collection where combinations of sub-documents in a list are unique.

**Allowed is:**
The following permissions are allowed, as there is also resourceID in the other example which shall not hurt the unique index

```
{
    "permission_name": "read",
    "role_id": 1,
    "value": "ALLOW",
    "attributes": [{
        "key": "folderID",
        "value": "1"
    }],
}
```

```
{
    "permission_name": "read",
    "role_id": 1,
    "value": "ALLOW",
    "attributes": [{
        "key": "folderID",
        "value": "1"
    },
    {
        "key": "resourceID",
        "value": "1"  
    }]
}
```

**Not allowed is**:
That the following entry is **two times** in the database

```
{
    "permission_name": "read",
    "role_id": 1,
    "value": "ALLOW",
    "attributes": [{
        "key": "folderID",
        "value": "1"
    }],
}
```

But when I create an index using:
`db.permissions.createIndex({"permission_name", "role_id", "attributes.key", "attributes.value"}, {unique: true})`, then I the example in "Allowed" is not possible due to duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

When MongoDB indexes an array of values, it creates a separate key in the index for each array entry.

For the first document in the example, the key would be (using `|` to represent field boundaries):

```
"read"|1|"folderID"|"1"
```

For the second document, there would be 2 keys added to the index:

```
"read"|1|"folderID"|"1"
"read"|1|"resourceID"|"1"
```

Setting `unique:true` on an index disallows duplicate keys in the index.  Since these 2 documents would both create the key `"read"|1|"folderID"|1`, inserting both is not permitted.

If you were able to index the array as a single entity there would still be problems, since array and field order both matter, so the following arrays would all be considered different:

```
"attributes": [{"key": "folderID",
                "value": "1"},
               {"key": "resourceID",
                "value": "1"  }]
```

```
"attributes": [{"key": "resourceID",
                "value": "1"  },
               {"key": "folderID",
                "value": "1"}]
```

```
"attributes": [{"key": "folderID",
                "value": "1"},
               {"value": "1",
                "key": "resourceID"}]
```

In order to ensure uniqueness of a combination of array elements, you would need to add a field that contains a value that is derived from the elements, and would uniquely identify a specific group of field/value pairs.

One possibility is to store the hash of the sorted field/value list, but this would require the application to recalculate the has each time the array changes, and any update would have to submit the new hash at the same time as the new array in order to be effective.